# Is hg commit supposed to inform Fogbugz?

Tags: mercurial, integration, commit, fogbugz

I've configured Mercurial to talk to Fogbugz as explained in their documentation. Should hg commit inform Fogbugz of the commit making the repository appear in the list of repositories and the commit message in the related bug as per the Bugz tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the instructions [here](http://newsupport.fogcreek.com/help/topics/sourcecontrol/setup/Mercurial.html), the trigger is not `commit`, but `push`: the hook is an `incoming` hook. The idea would appear to be that you have a central repo with this configuration installed, and when you push your change to the central repo it takes care of informing fogbugz. You *might* also be able to change the hook from `incoming` to `commit`, but it's probably better to pair the bug update with a push to some semi-official location.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a central repo yet. I've tried to integrate the hook with commit, but it seems nothing happened. I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, you can always make a clone on your local machine, set up its `.hg/hgrc` and push to that. All the `incoming` hook cares about is changesets that arrive by `push`.